# Android custom service - class implementation

Tags: java, android, multithreading, location, locationlistener

I'm a bit confused in deciding the way i should implement my background custom service class.

What I need :

1. location updates and activity recognition.
2. REST API call and the Geofence API.

I'm new to background processing in Android and I'm not sure how to implement this.

Is it possible to make a ThreadPoolExecutor (a task manager class, runnables, etc.) and deal with inter-thread communication ?

If yes,is it possible to listen to location updates inside a Thread class ?

for now, I'm using this library ( [Smart-location-lib](https://github.com/mrmans0n/smart-location-lib) ) to listen to location updates.

is there a better solution ?

Any help is greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way using Google API in background service
And you didn't explain what do you mean by activity recognition?

```
public class MyLocationService extends Service implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

public MyLocationService() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).
                    addConnectionCallbacks(this).
                    addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Location services started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    System.out.println("MyLocationService.onLocationChanged");
    // TODO with location updateshere
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000); // Update location every second

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    sendMyLocUpdate(loc, UserProfile.DRIVER);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Location services stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Location loc = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    sendMyLocUpdate(loc, UserProfile.PASSENGER);

    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you, but this code restarts when i close the app. How can i keep it from restarting ?

Comment: in onStartCommand() method call startForeground() of service and in onDestroy() method call stopForeground() method of this servies

Comment: the "startForeground()" is for showing to users (with a notification) that a service is running (Playing music, radio, etc.) which is not my case.

Comment: If that is not your case, then above only above services works for you or you can add you own logic. But whenever activity destroy which has started this service, services restart on activity destroy event